# Is it possible to display just the preview with markitUp?

Tags: jquery, text-editor, markitup

Is there a way to display only preview window with markitUp!, http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/, during text input from the user?

I found nothing about this in markitUp! documentation.

In fact, I think viewing source code of a message can be embarrassing for
an average user.

Comment: Do you mean embarrassing or confusing? I don't see why seeing your OWN source is embarrassing?

Comment: @Myles Gray My OWN source is not embarrassing for me, but I think to my visitors. :)

Comment: That is what I meant, the user would be embarrassed by their own source?